# Linux で NFS マウント先へファイルのコピーが出来ない

Tags: linux

下記のような構成で、LAN通信を通じPCAからPCBへ共有ファルダを設定しmountしています。
PCAにあるファイルをPCBへコピーしたのですが、一定の容量以上になるとコピーができません。
現象として、フリーズします。これを解決したいのですが、どういった方法を取るべきでしょうか？

簡単な構成は以下となります。

**PCA**

・PC:デスクトップ型PC
・OS:Linux(CentOS 7)
　※mount設定方法は以下
　mount -t nfs -o soft,rw,noac,lookupcache=none,retrans=1,timeo=10,retry=1 PCBのipアドレス
://home/VVV/root /home/AAA/BBB/SharedFolder/

**PCB**
・PC:デスクトップ型PC
・OS:Windows10内に、VirtualBoxのLinux(CentOS 8)がある。
・ファイルシステムをNFSとして設定する。
　※exportsファイルの設定内容は以下
　/home/VVV/root PCBのIP/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_root_squash)
　
　以下も参照
　https://pystyle.info/linux-how-to-mount-directory-on-another-machine/

#### 試したこと

・1.5kb程度のファイルをコピーすることは可能です。しかし、それ以上になるとコピーができません。
・PCAから以下のようなコマンドを使うと書き込み失敗エラーを表示しました。
　rsync PCAにあるファイル mount先のファイルパス

お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 単に「エラーになる」だけでなく、なにかメッセージが表示されているならそのままを質問に貼り付けてください。 / 単純な例だとコピー先に十分な空き領域が無くて失敗している可能性が考えられます。

Comment: NFSは前提で, 差し替え不可能なものですか？ NFS以外のリモートマウントや, そもそもリモートマウント使わず 普通に(リモートへの)コピーなどの方法は採れませんか？

Comment: 「現在、NFSサーバで行う必要があります。案件上の制約で、、」ということなら NFSの設定で"遅延を解消"させたい / スループットを改善したいなど, [質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/95609/edit)に記したほうがよいでしょう。
また, そうであれば, NFSの使用してるバージョン, TCP or UDP どちらの接続か なども追記したほうがよいでしょう。 / また rsync を**何の理由で**使用しているのか不明です。cp で構わないのでは？

Answer (score 0):

> 現象として、フリーズします。これを解決したいのですが、どういった方法を取るべきでしょうか？

どういった方法がよいのか, は ファイルの利用頻度やネットワークトラフィックの状況がわからないため何とも言えないかも

1. NFSオプションを微調整してみる
2. (NFS以外) ほかの種類の リモート・ファイル・システムをマウント
3. (リモートマウント関係なく) (rsync もしくは scp などで) リモートマシンへのコピーを行う

などが考えられるはず
「フリーズ」ということだけど, 単に**時間かかってる**だけでしょう

リモートマウントとしては sshfs が考えられたが開発終了のため, 以下もあるかもしれません

- [Rclone](https://rclone.org/)
- gigazine.net 記事 [CDC File Transfer](https://gigazine.net/news/20230110-google-stadia-cdc-file-transfer/)

---

##### (追記) NFS高速化

コメントにより, NFSからの変更はできないらしいので
NFSオプションなどについて

① rsyncと NFS
なぜ rsync使用しているのか現時点では不明だけど,
差分コピー目的なら以下を検証・計時してみるとよいでしょう
(rsync+NFS の組み合わせが一番遅い可能性があるので, 別の方法の検討も兼ねて)

- ローカルから NFS-directory (現状の方法)
- ローカルから NFS-directory (`cp` などでコビー)
- ローカルからホスト名(または IPアドレス)指定したリモートへのコピー (`rsync`)
- ローカルからホスト名(または IPアドレス)指定したリモートへのコピー (`scp` 利用)

コメントによると, scpでは読み込み・書き込みエラーが発生とのことだけど
それだけでは意味わかりません (指定間違えてるのでは？)

② NFSオプション
NFSオプションは `sync` 指定を `async` にすると高速になるでしょう(反応が)
ただしデメリットがあるのでその点は注意が必要です

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
1./etc/exportsファイルにある設定内容を変更してみるということでしょうか？
2.これは外部からインストールするということでしょうか？今回、外部からインストールすることが厳しいため難しいです。
3.scpで確認しましたが、結果はダメでした、、

Comment: NFS使うならマウントオプション rsize, wsize, timeo, retrans, など調整してみてはどうかということ。他の mountは, NFSではない別のリモートマウント方法。それが無理ならば(なにか理由あるなら)質問に記してください。scp がダメとは どういうエラーですか？どう指定しましたか？

Comment: NSFマウントオプション rsize, wsize, timeo, retransは試しました。
現在、rseize=1048576,wsize=1048576,timeo=10,retrans=1にしましたが、これらによってマウントはできませんでした。
現在、NFSサーバで行う必要があります。案件上の制約で、、
scpで行う場合、読み込み・書き込みエラーが発生しました。scpのオプションは今なにも設定していません。